# Trigger should be activated every 5 minutes, but it doesn't happen

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, triggers

The sequence of activations does not follow even a time logic, as shown here:

[image]

It is enabled based on time every 5 minutes.

The script I use is very simple:

```
function ProjetoNovasLigas() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange('Página1!A2').setFormula('=TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm")');
  ss.getRange('Página1!A2').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!A2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!K2:M').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!O2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!D2:D').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!E2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!K2:M').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!O2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!D2:D').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!E2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!K2:M').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!O2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!D2:D').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!E2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!K2:M').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!O2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!D2:D').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!E2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!K2:M').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!O2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!D2:D').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!E2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  if (ss.getSheetByName('Página1').getRange("C2").getValues()[0][0]=="Limpar"){
    ss.getRange('Página1!E2:E1000000').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  };
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2:V1000000').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2').setFormula('=IFERROR(FILTER(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),ISNA(MATCH(RIGHT(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),"(https?:\\/\\/([\\w.-]+\\/){7})","($1)")),LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),"(https?:\\/\\/([\\w.-]+\\/){7})","($1)")))-44),Sheet2!D:D, 0))))),300,1),ISNA(MATCH(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),300,1), X:X, 0)))\n)');
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2:V').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!V2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!U2:U').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!S2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!W2:W').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!X2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2:V1000000').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2').setFormula('=IFERROR(FILTER(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),ISNA(MATCH(RIGHT(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),"(https?:\\/\\/([\\w.-]+\\/){7})","($1)")),LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),"(https?:\\/\\/([\\w.-]+\\/){7})","($1)")))-44),Sheet2!D:D, 0))))),300,1),ISNA(MATCH(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),300,1), X:X, 0)))\n)');
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2:V').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!V2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!U2:U').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!S2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!W2:W').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!X2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2:V1000000').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2').setFormula('=IFERROR(FILTER(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),ISNA(MATCH(RIGHT(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),"(https?:\\/\\/([\\w.-]+\\/){7})","($1)")),LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),"(https?:\\/\\/([\\w.-]+\\/){7})","($1)")))-44),Sheet2!D:D, 0))))),300,1),ISNA(MATCH(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),300,1), X:X, 0)))\n)');
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2:V').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!V2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!U2:U').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!S2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!W2:W').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!X2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2:V1000000').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2').setFormula('=IFERROR(FILTER(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),ISNA(MATCH(RIGHT(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),"(https?:\\/\\/([\\w.-]+\\/){7})","($1)")),LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),"(https?:\\/\\/([\\w.-]+\\/){7})","($1)")))-44),Sheet2!D:D, 0))))),300,1),ISNA(MATCH(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),300,1), X:X, 0)))\n)');
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2:V').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!V2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!U2:U').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!S2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!W2:W').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!X2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2:V1000000').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2').setFormula('=IFERROR(FILTER(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),ISNA(MATCH(RIGHT(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),"(https?:\\/\\/([\\w.-]+\\/){7})","($1)")),LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),"(https?:\\/\\/([\\w.-]+\\/){7})","($1)")))-44),Sheet2!D:D, 0))))),300,1),ISNA(MATCH(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),300,1), X:X, 0)))\n)');
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2:V').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!V2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!U2:U').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!S2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!W2:W').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!X2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2:V1000000').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2').setFormula('=IFERROR(FILTER(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),ISNA(MATCH(RIGHT(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),"(https?:\\/\\/([\\w.-]+\\/){7})","($1)")),LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),"(https?:\\/\\/([\\w.-]+\\/){7})","($1)")))-44),Sheet2!D:D, 0))))),300,1),ISNA(MATCH(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(Q2:Q,ISNA(MATCH(Q2:Q, S2:S, 0)),VALUE(TEXT(O2:O&" "&P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))<=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))+"1:00"),300,1), X:X, 0)))\n)');
  ss.getRange('Página1!V2:V').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!V2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!U2:U').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!S2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!W2:W').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!X2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  if (ss.getSheetByName('Página1').getRange("A4").getValues()[0][0]=="Limpar"){
    ss.getRange('Página1!X2:X1000000').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  };
}
```

Final Detail:
My account has nothing left, it was created only for this spreadsheet and this script. So it's not going over any limits, I have another account with several and several spreadsheets with 5 minute triggers and all work perfectly. But this one specifically for this account doesn't work correctly.

There are scripts that I use that are infinitely more complex and heavy, all work 100% well. I'm finding this very strange, there is no logical explanation for what is happening. At least I can't find fault with what I know about it.

**I wonder if there is anything that can be done to solve this.**

Comment: So the first screenshot is the actual time intervals for the trigger? How long does it take the script to run when you run it manually or are there any errors?

Comment: @JamesD When I run manually, it works perfectly. It completes in no time at most: 40 seconds. And the picture is showing when the shots were taken. There should be a 5 minute time limit between each of them, but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Trigger usage is limited by [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

So, e.g. for a consumer account, there is the maximum limit of 90 min triggers total runtime per day.

If you run a trigger every 5 minutes, that is 24 x 12 times a day and if the average execution time amounts to 30 s - the total run time is 24 x 12 x 30 s / day = 144 min / day > 90 min / day

Comment: Now I understand ... The problem is not the amount of shots but the amount of time used in each shot. In order not to exceed the limit, it automatically divides this time I have all day, so as not to be blocked. Making it give these larger gaps between shots.